# To to sum cells in an excel column that fall between cells in the column the fit a specific criteria

Tags: excel, count, sum

I have an excel column that consists of a 1s or 0s like so:

```
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
```

I would like to be able to count how many 1s there are after there are 2 consecutive 1s and before 6 consecutive 0s (so in this case I would get a result of 6). I have to do this for about 200 columns so a formula that automatically does this would be really useful. Please can you tell me if it possible to do this, and, if so, how?
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: why isn't the answer 7?

Comment: if you have a 1 proceeded by 2 consecutive 1's and followed by 6 consecutive 0, does it get counted once for meeting both criteria or counted twice?

Comment: If the last number in the list is a 1 proceeded by a 0, does it still get counted as the next 6 entries do not exist?

Answer (score 0):

OK convoluted answer for you but it does work.  It works on the premise that its 1 and 0 which is equivalent of true and false.  It also assumes that you can create helper columns

1)  Make sure there are at least two blank rows above your data

2)  In a blank column use the following formula and copy down.  Also copy to the right if you are dealing with multiple adjacent columns.

```
=IF(AND(A3,OR(AND(A1,A2,NOT(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2)))),NOT(OR(A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,ISBLANK(A4),ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A6),ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(A8),ISBLANK(A9))))),1,0)
```

an easier to read alternate formula that also works based on the assumption that there are only blank cells below your column of data is:

```
=--AND(A3=1,OR(SUM(A1:A2)=2,AND(SUM(A4:A9)=0,NOT(ISBLANK(A9)))))
```

3)  Take the sum of all the helper columns created in step 2.

[image: POC]